# Publish a Xamarin.Android app

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-manifest, android-permissions

i can't figure out, how i correctly publish and sign an app created with Xamarin.Android in VS. i followed the Instructions in Xamarins "development Center" (Click [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release))

but the app still asks for development tools permissions when i want to install it. do i have to create a keystore manually before i hit Publishing or how does this works correctly?

[image]

My Manifest looks exactly like this:
[image]

Comment: even with creating a keystore with the keytool it didn't work

Comment: What does "development tools permissions" mean? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Screenshot added as requested

Comment: Are you just trying to get rid of that permission from the list?  If it's part of your app's manifest then it will show up on the list when you go to install the application.

Comment: there is no permission like that in my Manifest file, but... could it come along with the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ?

Comment: I think you're right!  If you are using a permissions group (such as STORAGE) then the 'Development tools' permission with that explicit subtext may be bundled up with it.  I did find the 'Development tools' permission group on the Android developer site here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group.html#DEVELOPMENT_TOOLS

Comment: added my manifest. thats all thats in there for now. didn't need other things up to now.